# Round neck blouse with short sleeves or short sleeve round neck blouse

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I came across these two sentences which refer to the same thing.

> Round neck blouse with short sleeves.
> Short sleeve round neck blouse

Is the second sentence more *correct* than the first one? I'm thinking blouse has sleeves while tank top is without sleeves. The first sentence seems to mean it is a tank top with sleeves which makes it a blouse?

Why does the sleeve become plural when ***with*** is use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say *short sleeved blouse*, but apart from that the two descriptions are equivalent.

A typical blouse is cut like a shirt, with buttons and a collar, and either long or short sleeves. I have one without sleeves; I call it a blouse because it buttons down the front. A T-shirt or a tank top (vest top in British English) is not a blouse because it is made of a knitted fabric and is pulled on over the head. (I'm talking typical garments here, not a hard-and-fast rule.)

Comment: Hi wonder if it is applicable to three quarter sleeves? for e.g. three quarter sleeved blouse?

Comment: I think that expression would be unremarkable in everyday conversation.